# Equivalent functionality to Access/VBA CHOOSE function in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to the CHOOSE function in MySQL.

I have a function in Access that I'm trying to convert into mySQL that basically looks like the below:

CHOOSE(CURRENT_PERIOD-1,PERIOD1, PERIOD2, PERIOD3, PERIOD4, PERIOD5, PERIOD6, PERIOD7, PERIOD8, PERIOD9, PERIOD10,PERIOD11,PERIOD12)

The function in this case if the current period was 5 would return PERIOD4 as the choose function would return the 4th in the series above.

I suppose I could run a nested if statement to perform the above but it would be a huge nested IF statement and I have 12 of these fields that contain this.  Is there any function or method that would work similarly to this without the query taking forever to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [case statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

```
case CURRENT_PERIOD-1
  when 1 then PERIOD1
  when 2 then PERIOD2
  ..
end case
```